# Java - Classpath issue with 64-bit system

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, 64-bit, classpath

I have completed my project on  windows7 - 32-bit system now I am trying to run this project on Windows7 - 64-bit system. 
While installing it I am getting this error:

"The archive: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/bin/bootstrap.jar which is referenced by the class path, does not exist."

I am using Eclipse and my server is tomcat 7.0
I have reinstalled the tomcat but not getting the solution. I have installed the same project in other 32-bit system,where it is running properly but I am getting the same error in other 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

In your project's build path (in `.classpath` eclipse managed file)  you have added entry of external jar which is pointing to location

```
 C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

this jar file doesn't exist in your new machine or it doesn't like spaces in the path, so correct the path or go for dependency managers like maven

Comment: This file is there in the Folder.